# Difference in Difference in R (Callaway & Sant'Anna)

Tags: regression

I'm trying to implement the DiD package by Callaway and Sant'Anna in my master thesis, but I'm coming across errors when I run the DiD code and when I try to view the summary.

```
did1 <- att_gt(yname = "countgreen",
              gname = "signing_year", 
              idname = "investorid",
              tname = "dealyear", 
              data = panel8)
```

This code warns me that:

```
"Be aware that there are some small groups in your dataset.
  Check groups: 2006,2007,2008,2011. Dropped 109 observations that had missing data.overlap condition violated for 2009 in time period 2001Not enough control units for group 2009 in time period 2001 to run specified regression"
```

This error is repeated several hundred times.

Does this mean I need to re-match my treatment firms to control firms using a 1:3 ration (treat:control) rather than the 1:1 I used previously?

Then when I run this code:

```
summary(did1)
```

I get this message:

```
Error in Math.data.frame(list(`mpobj$group` = c(2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, : non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: mpobj$att
```

I'm really not too sure what this means.

Can anyone help trouble shoot?

Thanks,
Rory

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the DiD package but i can't answer about the :`summary(did1)`

If you do `str(did1)` you should have something like this :

```
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ cluster    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ price_scal : num  -0.572 -0.132 0.891 1.091 -0.803 ...
 $ hd_scal    : num  -0.778 0.63 0.181 -0.24 0.244 ...
 $ ram_scal   : num  -0.6937 0.00479 0.46411 0.00653 -0.31204 ...
 $ screen_scal: num  -0.457 2.642 -0.195 2.642 -0.325 ...
 $ ads_scal   : num  0.315 -0.889 0.472 0.47 -0.822 ...
 $ trend_scal : num  -0.604 1.267 -0.459 -0.413 1.156 ...
```

But in your case you should have one variable `mpobj$att` that is a factor or a str column.

Maybe this should also make the DiD code run.